# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Makefile

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, cgal

I deployed CGAL in Mac OS X Yosimite try to compile some graphic codes. And I've deployed cmake, Qt4, boost in my Mac.

But after I cmake the files, when I "make", I get errors like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MedialAxisSimplification3D::MedialAxisSimplification3D(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)", referenced from:
  _main in main.cpp.o
  "MedialAxisSimplification3D::~MedialAxisSimplification3D()", referenced from:
  _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I wonder why this happens and how can I solve it.

I will appreciate for your answers!

1.This is the header files which define some class and functions -- MedialAxisSimplification3D.h

```
#include <QtGui>

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtOpenGL>

#include "ThreeDimensionalShape.h"
#include "GLWidget.h"
#include "ui_medial_axis.h"
#include "PsRender/PsRender.h"

class MedialAxisSimplification3D : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
    MedialAxisSimplification3D(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0);
    ~MedialAxisSimplification3D();

private slots:
//......
};
```

2.This is the source file which implement the codes -- MedialAxisSimplification3D.cpp

```
#include "medialaxissimplification3d.h"
#include <ctime>

// construction function
MedialAxisSimplification3D::MedialAxisSimplification3D(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    //......
}

MedialAxisSimplification3D::~MedialAxisSimplification3D()
{
}
```

3.My cmakelist.txt is post as following:

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_cmake_script
# This is the CMake script for compiling a CGAL application.

project (GeneratorDemo)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)
if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_PATCH_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER 2.8.3)
  cmake_policy(VERSION 2.8.4)  
else()
  cmake_policy(VERSION 2.6)
endif()

find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Qt4)

include(${CGAL_USE_FILE})

set( QT_USE_QTXML    TRUE )
set( QT_USE_QTMAIN   TRUE )
set( QT_USE_QTSCRIPT  TRUE )
set( QT_USE_QTOPENGL  TRUE )

find_package(Qt4)

include_directories (BEFORE ../../include)

if ( CGAL_FOUND AND CGAL_Qt4_FOUND AND QT4_FOUND )

  include(${QT_USE_FILE})
  #--------------------------------
  # Demo
  #--------------------------------
  # UI files (Qt Designer files)
  qt4_wrap_ui( DT_UI_FILES medial_axis.ui )

  # qrc files (resources files, that contain icons, at least)
  qt4_add_resources ( DT_RESOURCE_FILES ./medial_axis.qrc )

  # use the Qt MOC preprocessor on classes that derives from QObject
  qt4_generate_moc( "main.cpp" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/main.moc" )

  # The executable itself.
  add_executable  ( main main.cpp main.moc ${DT_UI_FILES} ${DT_RESOURCE_FILES} )

  add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS main )

  # Link with Qt libraries
  target_link_libraries( main ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
  # And with CGAL libraries
  target_link_libraries( main ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )

else()

  message(STATUS "NOTICE: This demo requires CGAL, and Qt4, and will not be compiled.")

endif()
```

4.Full command file:

```
xuelanqings-MacBook-Pro:qmat Toutou$ make 
[ 20%] Generating qrc_medial_axis.cxx
RCC: Warning: No resources in    '/Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/medial_axis.qrc'.
[ 40%] Generating main.moc
/Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/main.cpp:0: Note: No relevant classes found.     No output generated.
[ 60%] Generating ui_medial_axis.h
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/medialaxissimplification3d.h:10:
/Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/GLWidget.h:240:2: warning: 'GLUquadricObj' is
      deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        GLUquadricObj *spherequadric;
        ^
//System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glu.h:224:26: note: 
      'GLUquadricObj' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
typedef class GLUquadric GLUquadricObj OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_9);
                         ^
In file included from /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/medialaxissimplification3d.h:10:
/Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/GLWidget.h:241:2: warning: 'GLUquadricObj' is
      deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        GLUquadricObj * conequadric;
        ^
//System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glu.h:224:26: note: 
      'GLUquadricObj' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
typedef class GLUquadric GLUquadricObj OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_9);
                         ^
2 warnings generated.
In file included from /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/medialaxissimplification3d.h:10:
/Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/GLWidget.h:240:2: warning: 'GLUquadricObj' is
      deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        GLUquadricObj *spherequadric;
        ^
//System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glu.h:224:26: note: 
      'GLUquadricObj' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
typedef class GLUquadric GLUquadricObj OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_9);
                         ^
In file included from /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/main.cpp:1:
In file included from     /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/medialaxissimplification3d.h:10:
/Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/GLWidget.h:241:2: warning: 'GLUquadricObj' is
      deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        GLUquadricObj * conequadric;
        ^
//System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glu.h:224:26: note: 
      'GLUquadricObj' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
typedef class GLUquadric GLUquadricObj OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_9);
                         ^
2 warnings generated.
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/qrc_medial_axis.cxx.o
Linking CXX executable main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MedialAxisSimplification3D::MedialAxisSimplification3D(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "MedialAxisSimplification3D::~MedialAxisSimplification3D()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

5.Makefile--auto generated by cmake,

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.2

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /opt/local/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /opt/local/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    /opt/local/bin/ccmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /opt/local/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/CMakeFiles /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /Users/Toutou/Documents/qmat/qmat/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named main

# Build rule for target.
main: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 main
.PHONY : main

# fast build rule for target.
main/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/main.dir/build
.PHONY : main/fast

main.o: main.cpp.o
.PHONY : main.o

# target to build an object file
main.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
.PHONY : main.cpp.o

main.i: main.cpp.i
.PHONY : main.i

# target to preprocess a source file
main.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.i
.PHONY : main.cpp.i

main.s: main.cpp.s
.PHONY : main.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
main.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.s
.PHONY : main.cpp.s

qrc_medial_axis.o: qrc_medial_axis.cxx.o
.PHONY : qrc_medial_axis.o

# target to build an object file
qrc_medial_axis.cxx.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/main.dir/qrc_medial_axis.cxx.o
.PHONY : qrc_medial_axis.cxx.o

qrc_medial_axis.i: qrc_medial_axis.cxx.i
.PHONY : qrc_medial_axis.i

# target to preprocess a source file
qrc_medial_axis.cxx.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/main.dir/qrc_medial_axis.cxx.i
.PHONY : qrc_medial_axis.cxx.i

qrc_medial_axis.s: qrc_medial_axis.cxx.s
.PHONY : qrc_medial_axis.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
qrc_medial_axis.cxx.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/main.dir/qrc_medial_axis.cxx.s
.PHONY : qrc_medial_axis.cxx.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... main"
    @echo "... main.o"
    @echo "... main.i"
    @echo "... main.s"
    @echo "... qrc_medial_axis.o"
    @echo "... qrc_medial_axis.i"
    @echo "... qrc_medial_axis.s"
.PHONY : help
#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Comment: Make sure your architectures match; i.e. install the 64-bit library or compile as 32-bit.

Comment: First interesting thing: what is the architecture of the `main.cpp.o`? I am not familiar with Os X, but I think the command `file` probably should show. Also it would be nice if you'd included in the question full call to the compiler *(with options and etc.)* — it should be just before the errors.

Comment: I added the full command file on 4th part. And the main.cpp is the main sourcefile which include some headers, which headers include the "medialaxissimplification3d.h" and others.

Comment: @LanqingXue **You have not added the full command line**. What Hi-Angel meant was the compile and/or link command actually generating the error message, not the make command and its outputs. The error message means that the object file or library containing the missing symbols is missing in the link command.

Comment: @Walter, Does it mean this:
    cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/opt/local/lib/cmake/
and after that I using 
    make
then, generated the error code. 
I haven't notice that I've accept the answer  by Tim Smit. And the problem haven't been solved. Thanks for notification!

Comment: @LanqingXue No, the compile and/or link command must commence with `g++`,  `c++`, `gcc`, `clang` (or similar), or `ld`. There may be a switch to use with your makefile that makes it more verbatim, i.e. printing out each command -- in fact, this is the usual behaviour, but is suppressed in your case by the `$(VERBOSE).SILENT:` entry in the makefile. Comment that line out and try to re-make. Then tell us the last command before the error. (however, your makefile uses sub-makes with other makefiles, which in turn may also switch verbose to silent ...)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, Thanks for your answer! I find I build the library as x86_64 and after I change the build function as x86_64 and i386 the problem solved! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error code is a bit deceiving, and has nothing to do with 32- or 64-bit libraries. If you have copied the code directly, you seem to be missing a semicolon after your class definition, so your constructor and destructor are unknown to your main.cpp:

```
class MedialAxisSimplification3D : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

  public:
    MedialAxisSimplification3D(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0);
    ~MedialAxisSimplification3D();

    private slots:
//......
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I'm sorry that I missing the semicolon when I copy the codes. But it does really exist in the source code.

Comment: @LanqingXue, indeed the expected error message would've probably been different. I've had some pretty well-hidden error messages when using building tools like QMake so I figured this might be it. --If not it would be good to see your Makefile as Hi-Angel suggested as it looks like the MedialAxisSimplification3D class is not being linked correctly.

Comment: @TimSmit, Thank you very much and I add the Makefile in the 5th paragraph. And the Makefile was generated by building tools--cmake. I am not very sure about the accuracy of the Makefile, coz I'm new at graphics. Thank you.

Comment: @LanqingXue You've accepted this answer, but how does it answer your question? This indicates that you're no longer looking for another answer and that the problem is solved -- but how? what was the problem???